# How to connect to intranet over VPN if on the same subnet?

Tags: vpn

I have a VPN Server running at home a few thousand kilometers away, providing access to my network on 192.168.0.x. This works perfectly in most cases, but once I am in a network that is using the same subnet 192.168.0.x it will fail.

Unfortunatelly this is sometimes the case and I can not change either of the subnets. Is there a way to reconfigure my remote VPN server to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you connect over IPv6? Those numbers likely are not the same (and IP v6 is now over 2 decades old, so it should be supported).  Otherwise, changing you home IPs to something less common is the normal solution (albeith the one you did not ask for).

Answer (score 1):

maybe adding specific routes to specific remote server, hoping it doesn't have another IP you need to access on your corporate network.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757323%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: good idea, but unfrotunatelly does not work on iOS

Comment: Why not? Which error do you get? The basis is the same so iOS should support it, even if you have to use slightly different commands.

Comment: iOS *has* commands?

Comment: I supposed that after rooting it (the first thing you do after buying it) you get access to a decent shell.